# Numpy subclass attribute slicing

Tags: python, numpy, slice

`Myclass`   is a `numpy.ndarray` subclass, intended to represent a set of images that change over time. To each image there is a set of metadata, like time, ambient temperature and camera temperature. I've stored these metadata in a list of dictionaries, so that each dictionary corresponds to a layer in the array (`myclass.metadata[0]` is the dictionary that corresponds to the image in `myclass[0]`).

I've also overloaded `getattr()` to make the items in the dictionary accessible by their key, so that `myclass.etemp` yields e.g. `[24.9, 25.0, 25.1]`.

When I slice my Myclass-object, how do I achieve that my attribute-array gets sliced the same way?

Now if I do `myobject[1].etemp`, I get  `[24.9, 25.0, 25.1]`, but I want `[25.0]`.

This is my class:

```
class Stack(numpy.ndarray):
    props= [
            'version',
            'width',
            'height',
            'shotrange',
            'calibrange',
            'unit',
            'irb_fname',
            'fidx',
            'distance',
            'etemp',
            'zoom',
            'ctemp',
            'date',
            'recdate',
            'rectime',
            ]

    def __new__(cls, input_array, mdata=None):
        obj = numpy.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        if isinstance(mdata, collections.Iterable): # when reading from text file
            obj.mdata = mdata
        else:
            obj.mdata = [arr.mdata[0] for arr in input_array] # when combining Stack-type objects
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.mdata = getattr(obj, 'mdata', None)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print(numpy.shape(self))
        if numpy.rank(self) < 3: # we're looking at a single slice
            pass
        if name == 'starttime':
            return self.mdata[0]['date']
        elif name == 'time':
            return [(item['date'] - self.mdata[0]['date']).total_seconds() for item in self.mdata]
        elif name in Stack.props:
            return [item[name] for item in self.mdata]
        else:
            raise AttributeError
```

What do I need to do to implement that behavior? Or are there other better way to store the metadata?

Comment: Also may want to look into PyTables, a nice way of storing data and associated metadata. Super fast also!

Comment: I am already using h5py to store the data on disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `__getitem__` method.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getitem__(self,items):
        print items

f = Foo()
f[1,2,3]
f[1:3]
f[1,1:3,2:3]
```

This returns:

```
1
(1, 2, 3)
slice(1, 3, None)
(1, slice(1, 3, None), slice(2, 3, None))
```

Within your `__getitem__`, you'll need to slice the attributes appropriately as well handling the above cases.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was failing at, but now it seems the problem is solved. I stumbled upon `numpy.ndarray.__array__()`. My `__getitem__()` checks now if `self` is of rank 3, and only then modifies the metadata. A new Stack object is returned on each call.

Comment: Also I had to modify `__getslice__(self, i, j)` to call `self[i:j:None]`, so that slices become extended slices and are passed to `__getitem__()`. Shouldn't that happen per default?

Comment: For backward compatibility, `__getslice__` is tried before `__getitem__`. So if the base class implements `__getslice__`, you will have to override that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have your properties attached to your objects in array, and not to your array may be of help.

Comment: But wouldn't I then lose the ability to do something like myclass[0,0,0] and myclass[0:3]? That was my main reason for subclassing ndarray